# UIScrollview inside Uiscrollview and both vertically scrollable

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, io, uikit

Yeah, I know that apple does not recommend this, but can anyone give me some advice how to achieve the following behaviour:

- 1 scroll is fullscreen + 200px content height, f.e.
- 2 scroll is nested in parent, conent size is also bigger than frame

firstly, the 1st scroll is scrolled, and when it reaches it's border the second begins to scroll.

Any snippet of code and any idea (even scary one) is appreciated, thx

Comment: Just a suggestion. If any of the scroll view has only text then I would suggest you to go for `UITextView` instead of `UIScrollView`

Comment: Unfortunately, the content of both scrollviews is not text

Comment: Oops..!! Ok. I like your try but are sure you want to do something like this?

Comment: I guess you can disable scrolling your 2nd scroll view initially, after you scrolled the 1st one to it's border, disable scrolling on the 1st scroll view and enable scrolling on the 2nd scroll view.
to enable / disable scrolling, you can set the property `scrollEnabled` on the UIScrollView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/stuartjmoore/SMHeadedList) is the one of possible solutions